# Access Multiple Children From BaseClass/Link Base to children

Tags: c#, .net

How can I access the children from a base class?

My classes are setup like this:

```
abstract class Bank
{
    public Bank(int One, int Two)
    {
    }
}

public class Checking : Bank
{
    public Checking(int One, int Two) : base(One, Two)
    {
    }
}

public class Savings : Parent
{
    public Savings(int One, int Two) : base(One, Two)
    {
    }
}
```

How can I have the Bank class instantiate both a checking and savings when needed?

I want to do something like:

```
Bank B = new Savings(....);
B = new Checkings(....);

B.Savings.Foo(......);
B.Checkings.Foo(.....);
```

Comment: `public class Savings : Parent` - Did you mean `public class Savings : Bank`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create class which will hold both instances `Checkings` and `Savings`.

```
public class BankTuple
{
    public BankTuple(int one, int two)
    {
        Checkings = new Checkings(one, two);
        Savings = new Savings(one, two);
    }

    public Checkings Checkings { get; private set; }

    public Savings Savings { get; private set; }
}
```

Then use it:

```
var tuple = new BankTuple(1, 2);
// tuple.Checkings
// tuple.Savings
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `B` can hold reference to only one object in memory. If you need to hold references to several objects consider using collection:

```
List<B> banks = new List<B>();
banks.Add(new Savings());
banks.Add(new Checkings());
```

Also I believe you have a typo - `Savings` should inherit from `Bank`, not from some `Parent`.

Comment: I know. It was just an example. I want to do something similar though. How do I access the children of the base?

Oops.. Yeah the savings should inherit from Bank.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames what do you mean by access children of the base class? Child **is a** Base class. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

In Object oriented programming, the parent class should *never* know about the children AFAIK. Will update with link as to why.

Comment: Why they can't? It's design smell, but it's not restricted. Even in framework. See `FileSystemInfo`